# Sharing power source for LED strip and stepper motor

Tags: power-supply, stepper-motor, led-strip

I'm making an AC powered lamp with retractable console uling **12 V** LED strip and stepper motor. Originally no automation was planned so simplest AC-DC converter was bought.
Like this (declared by manufacturer as LED driver): [image: ND-P30-IP20-12V] except that my have lower characteristics:

- Wattage = 0..15 W
- Iout max = 1.25 A
- Output voltage = 12V DC

LED strips (2 pieces) being powered from this supply consumes **310 mA** each. Which gives **7.44 W** total.

Stepper motor (M42SP-4NP) consumes **300 mA** at **12 V** resulting in **3.6 W**. Winding resistance is 40 Ohm. Also there is some neglectable power consumed by AVR mCU through LM1117 linear regulator.

Is it Ok to power all parts by the specified AC-DC converter or additional supply for motor and mCU should be used?

Also I'm doubting which type of transistor is better for switching LEDs - BJT or MOSFET?

Comment: 10W seems like a lot for an LED strip. High power LEDs, sure, but those aren't typically on a strip. What are the exact power ratings for your supply? Just the watts aren't as useful as knowing the voltage output and maximum current. The pictured supply outputs up to 2.5A at 12 V, but that would be 30W. Do the LEDs require 12V? Does the motor require 12V? The AVR is likely only a few mA tops, so like you said, it is negligible; however, a spike in current draw from other components could cause a brown out, resetting the MCU if you are near your power capacity.

Comment: Yes it should work, your PSU is rated at 15W output, so should be able to continuously supply enough current for all your components. Just make sure you have plenty of capacitance at the output of your linear regulator to allow for voltage droops / spikes when switching LED  and motor.